# Unexpected behaviour in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
foo_list = Foo.objects.all()[100:200]
print foo_list[0].id
print len(foo_list)
print foo_list[0].id
```

I expect that result of first and third print be eqaul but they are not.How this could be happen?

Comment: So whats the result?

Comment: It seems that after ** len(foo_list) ** value of foo_list changes, so id of first element of list are different.

Comment: Fortunately Alex does the job! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into the "wontfix" issue at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9006 --

> LIMIT queries without ORDER BY aren't guaranteed to return consistent
>   result sets

(depending on the underlying DB engine), and that's what your `[0]` indexing is causing to happen -- because despite the misleading name `foo_list` is **not** a list, it's queryset itself!  As documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/ ,

> Slicing an unevaluated `QuerySet` usually returns another unevaluated
>   `QuerySet`

Solution: **make** it a list:

```
foo_list = list(Foo.objects.all()[100:200])
```

and live happily ever after:-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

When you construct your `foo_list` in the first line, nothing happens on database. The query is not executed until you actually get an object from the queryset.

So, when you get `foo_list[0].id` for the first time, you actually *re-slice it*, thus running a `SELECT` statement asking for a single row. Now, when you call `len(foo_list)` you *force* the original queryset (which returns 100 rows) to be executed.

Since you run two different queries (one for a single row, and one for 100 rows) and did not specify an `order_by` clause, the two queries may (and do) return different results.